# Efficiently performing File I/O for non-sequential access of a large 3D grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, file-io

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to discretize a portion of 3D space into small cubes i.e. I'm turning a part of physical space (as described by its x,y,z Cartesian coordinates) into a 3D grid. Each element of this array has a `double` type distance value associated with it. The grid is stored as a 1D array where any point (x, y, z) is mapped onto the array index using:

`z + y*dim_xy + x*dim_x`, where `dim_xy` is the size of a 2D slice of the grid and `dim_x` is the size of a single axis (basically it's similar to what happens implicitly when you create a 3D array and access it using 3D index values).

**The problem:** I want to discretize a rather large 3D space at a very fine resolution. The resulting array is around 4-6GB in size. If I simply create the array using the `new` operator, my program crashes because of lack of RAM (in fact sometimes the entire system crashes for 5-6 minutes).

**My proposed solution, and what's wrong with it:** I tried to store the array as a binary file. The problem is that while sequential I/O operations are reasonably fast, non-sequential ones take considerable time. In my case, the distance values for the grid are computed in a breadth-first manner starting from a specified point. So even though the algorithm proceeds in a way where successive (x, y, z) points are processed sequentially (somewhat), the array indexes they map onto vary significantly from iteration to iteration. That's why I can't just create a smaller, temporary array, fill it with values and write it onto the file in one go.

My main problem is writing all the contents of the file in a time efficient manner. Right now, I'm using the `seek` function to jump to a specific location in the file (i.e. an index in the array) at every iteration, but it's taking like 5 minutes just to write a small 150MB file. Note that reading the file isn't that big a concern; once the file's written, the need to read it won't arise that often and I can accept the delay associated with non-sequential access. I just need a fast way to create the file in the first place.

Comment: I would try to memory map the file. I assume you are working on a 64bit machine.

Comment: Yes. 64-bit machine running Linux. Don't memory mapped files involve RAM usage as well though? Or does the OS safely handle how much of the file can be loaded without the memory becoming full.

Comment: The OS should take care of actually clainimg the RAM where you actually make an access. So you rely on the OS instead of having to implement the segmentation yourself. Not wure it works but is easy to implement and (I think) worth a try.

Comment: Actually linear indexing makes it hard to allocate because the storage needs to be a big whole chunk. Try making an array of pointers and do `arr[x][y*dimxy + x*dimx]` or even `arr[z][y][x]` and let the allocator scatter rows/columns.

Comment: Or try using std::map or std::unordered_map on the outer-most dimension so that the storage can be allocated on-demand. IMO offloading the memory shortage problem to the kernel by giving it more swap is worth trying first rather than trying to move to memory mapped file directly.

Comment: Yeah but even then the solution probably won't scale well. I have 4GB RAM + 4GB swap partition, so if my grid ends up being 7GB in size there's not gonna be much memory to work with in the first place for the kernel to optimize.

Comment: Then either you use 7GB of memory mapped file plus 4GB of cache, or let the kernel use 4GB of memory plus 3GB of cache. The only difference is that the second approach forces other processes to use swap and slows down the whole system, while the first restricts your process to disk IO and only use physical memory conservatively.

Comment: Your problem doesn't scale well anyway because the problem size is well beyond hardware resources. I would suggest going back a little and ask yourself, is it possible to do block processing (so that only one block needs to be in the memory at any certain time), or is it possible to distribute the problem to multiple machines (currently the only way to scale above TBs of memory).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by marom you should use memory mapped files. But a way to obtain contiguous access is to store your data as a BSP or BVH (like a VP-tree or a kd-tree). Another way would be to use a space filling curve (like the 3d peano curve) to index the points.